# Can't find virtualization option in BIOS

Tags: bios, docker

So I have an AMD Ryzen 5 3600 and an Asus Motherboard Prime B550-K. I've tried updated the bios and enabling and disabling hyper-v but still can't find the optio. Running Windows 10 Pro btw

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the option I was looking for, it was under SVM, once I enabled it my problem was solved.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](https://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/996711)

Comment: @DaveM - The only option they could have accepted wasn't accurate and it certainly wasn't very helpful.  While this answer needed some help because it contained a "thank you" it certainly was the most accurate answer.

Answer (score -2):

I was looking up ASUS motherboards and noticed that they *mostly* use Asus UEFI BIOS (somewhat same layout as click bios) and to enable virtualization follow these steps.

1. Press **F2** key at startup to go into the BIOS.
2. Press the **right arrow key** to go into the **Advanced** tab then select **Virtualization Technology** then press the **enter** key.
3. Select **Enabled** and press the **enter** key.
4. Press the **F10** key and select **Yes** and press the **Enter** key to save changes and **reboot**.